# Insert data from another table multiple times?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert data from Table_A into Table_B .
Rules : Insert 2 records from Table_A into Table_B ,if the records already exits in Table_B,skip it and insert the next one.

eg:

```
Table_A

ID(Key)  Name
1      John
2      Noah
3      Mary
4      Roland
5      Ivan
```

```
Table B
ID  Name OtherColumns
1   John   xxxxxxxxx
4   Roland xxxxxxxxx
```

Result:

```
Table B
ID  Name OtherColumns
1   John   xxxxxxxxx
2   Noah   xxxxxxxxx
2   Noah   xxxxxxxxx
2   Noah   xxxxxxxxx
3   Mary   xxxxxxxxx
3   Mary   xxxxxxxxx
3   Mary   xxxxxxxxx
4   Roland xxxxxxxxx
```

This is my SQL query but it not works well

```
Declare 
i:= 0;

Begin
For i in 1..3 loop

insert into Table_B
(
ID,Name,OtherColumns
)
select 
(
ID,Name,'xxxxxxxxx'
)
from 
Table_A
where ID not in 
(
select ID from Table_B
)
and rownum < 3;
end loop ;
end ;
```

Anyone can tell me what is the problem ...?  >_<

Comment: `from Table_A where ID not in (select ID from Table_A)` – should be `table_b`, shouldn't it? This looks pretty strange, though, your database design at very least seems not to be correctly normalised – if not flawed entirely.

Comment: To Aconcagua : Sorry that's a writing mistake , "TABLE_B" is correct .

Comment: *it not works well* provides absolutely no information for anyone except you, because no one can see your screen and read your mind. Please, clarify the reason to have three instances of each source row in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rules: Insert 2 [copies of each] record from `Table_A` into `Table_B`, if the records already exits in `Table_B`, skip it and insert the next one.

Use a `MERGE` statement and a row generator to duplicate the rows:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_b dst
USING (
  SELECT a.*
  FROM   table_a a
         CROSS JOIN (
           SELECT LEVEL AS id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2
         ) l
) src
ON (src.id = dst.id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, name, othercolumns)
  VALUES (src.id, src.name, 'xxxxxxxxx');
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table_A ( ID, Name ) AS
SELECT 1, 'John'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Noah'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Mary'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Roland' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Ivan'   FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table_B (ID, Name, OtherColumns) AS
SELECT 1, 'John',   'xxxxxxxxx' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Roland', 'xxxxxxxxx' FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `MERGE` the table contains:

| ID | NAME | OTHERCOLUMNS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | xxxxxxxxx |
| 4 | Roland | xxxxxxxxx |
| 2 | Noah | xxxxxxxxx |
| 2 | Noah | xxxxxxxxx |
| 3 | Mary | xxxxxxxxx |
| 3 | Mary | xxxxxxxxx |
| 5 | Ivan | xxxxxxxxx |
| 5 | Ivan | xxxxxxxxx |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yw0iXxNy)